# Java - converting "this[int x, int y]"

Tags: java, this

What I am doing is transposing a c# project to java for practice in writing custom classes.
Unfortunately I cant figure out what the person is doing with "this" keyword inside the constructor.

```
// C# Code - How is this written in Java?
public Player this[int x, int y] 
{ 
    get { return squares[x, y]; } 
    set { squares[x, y] = value; } 
}
```

I have transposed a lot of the code and am kind of stuck on this. I cant seem to find any information on this particular instance in Java. does anyone have a good lead for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not in the constructor. That's the declaration of an [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). The Java equivalent would be something like:

```
public Player getPlayer(int x, int y)
{
    // Note: Java doesn't have "real" multidimensional arrays,
    // only arrays of arrays.
    return squares[x][y];
}

public Player setPlayer(int x, int y, Player player)
{
    squares[x][y] = player;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon... this helped A LOT. good to know that there are no actual multidimensional arrays...

Answer (score 0):

This is [Using Indexers (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This [blog](http://codeporting.com/blog/csharp-to-java-conversion/archive/2012/06/13/migrating-csharp-indexers-to-java-using-codeporting-csharp2java.html) has some ideas of how to port the C# indexer to java code.

Basically it can be realized in a java getter/setter:

```
public Player get(int x, int y) { return squares[x][y];}

public Player set(int x, int y, Player p) { squares[x][y] = p;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a constructor, that's an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Basically, this definition allows you to do:

```
Player playerAtOrigin = myGameBoard[0, 0];
```

In Java, only arrays have an indexer (e.g. `myArray[i]`), you cannot define your own indexers. Most likely, you'll want to translated this into two methods `getPlayerAt(int x, int y)` and `setPlayerAt(int x, int y, Player player)`.

Comment: cool, thanks for correcting me. im really new to java. how would that be transposed in java?

Comment: You'll want to make two methods for getting a player by its position and setting the player's position. In this case, these methods simply have to look in the `squares` array (as demonstrated in Jon Skeet's answer).